# Getting random urls from google and storing them into array

Tags: php, javascript

I need to check the connection time to some url, i do it using *curl* (i only know how to do it for 1 url at the time tho, my problem is that i need to check it for many urls, not just 1)

Here is an example of how i calculate the connection time:

```
$url1 = 'stackoverflow.com';
$curl1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($curl1);
$contime1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME);
echo $contime1;
```

now lets say instead of 'stackoverflow.com' url i wanted to use multiple urls, like this array list for example:

```
$imones = array ("php.net","w3schools.com", "stackoverflow.com");
while (list(, $value) = each($imones)) {
$imoneslist = "$value<br />\n";
```

how do i put $imoneslist array into $url1?

Comment: You should not put "w3schools.com" into the list IMO.

Comment: ^ There has to be some bad with the good or it's going to be a biased list.

Comment: i put it as an random example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$imones = array ("php.net","w3schools.com", "stackoverflow.com");
foreach($imones as $url1) {
    $curl1 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_exec($curl1);
    $contime1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME);
    echo $url1 . ' took ' . $contime1 . ' seconds to connect<br />';
}
```

Tested. Sample result:

```
php.net took 0.032 seconds to connect 
w3schools.com took 0.124 seconds to connect 
stackoverflow.com took 0.016 seconds to connect
```

Comment: Don't use one stackoverflow question to ask two completely different questions. Start a new question for q2